# Pattern to authenticate the user in SceneDelegate.ContinueUserActivity?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I'm using Deeplinking on Xamarin.iOS.

I can't find a pattern to handle the link if the user has disconnected from my app.
In this case I need to redirect to the login page while waiting for the login to complete before leaving SceneDelegate.ContinueUserActivity, right?

What I've tried so far is to set a Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncAutoResetEvent in my login ViewController, then wait for it with the help of [AsyncHelpers](https://gist.github.com/ChrisMcKee/6664438). But the login UI is frozen.

```
[Export("scene:continueUserActivity:")]
public void ContinueUserActivity(UIScene scene, NSUserActivity userActivity)
{
    ....
    if (notAuthenticated)
    {
        // The user is not authenticated
        // Redirect to the Login Page

        LoginViewController lvc = new LoginViewController(true);

        if (Window.RootViewController == null)
        {
            var navController = new UINavigationController(lvc);

            Window.RootViewController = navController;
         }
         else
         {
              UINavigationController rootViewController = ((UINavigationController)Window.RootViewController);
              rootViewController.PopToRootViewController(true);
              rootViewController.PushViewController(lvc, true);
          }

          Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

          AsyncHelpers.RunSync(async() => await lvc.LoginFinishedOrCancelled.WaitAsync());
 
          ...
    }
}
```

As far as I know there is no way to make ContinueUserActivity async aware.

Answer (score 0):

You could invoke the line `AsyncHelpers.RunSync(async() => await lvc.LoginFinishedOrCancelled.WaitAsync());` in your login page instead of in SceneDelegate .

```
public bool isNeedLoad {get;set;}

public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
             
            if(isNeedLoad)
            {
               // ...AsyncHelpers.RunSync(async() => await lvc.LoginFinishedOrCancelled.WaitAsync());
              isNeedLoad = false ;
            }
            
           
        }
```

```
LoginViewController lvc = new LoginViewController(true){isNeedLoad  = true};

        if (Window.RootViewController == null)
        {
            var navController = new UINavigationController(lvc);

            Window.RootViewController = navController;
            Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
         }
         else
         {
              UINavigationController rootViewController = ((UINavigationController)Window.RootViewController);
              rootViewController.PopToRootViewController(true);
              rootViewController.PushViewController(lvc, true);
          }
```